# LayerKit iOS - newConversationWithParticipants is failing in swift 2.0 but do/catch is not catching anything from the thrown error

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, swift2, layer

```
do {
    self.conversation = try layerClient.newConversationWithParticipants(userSet, options: nil)
    print("Conversation was created: \(self.conversation)")
} catch let error {
    print("Conversation error: \(error)")
}
```

So basically, given the code sample above, NOTHING prints out using LayerKit and a successfully connected and authenticated LYRClient (layerClient in the code sample).

Watching the LYRClientDelegate, the layerClient in question is successfully connected and authenticated but it seems like the thrown error (keep in mind that LayerKit is written in Objective-C and the thrown error ACTUALLY comes from an objective-c **NSError conversion via Swift 2.0) just cuts the containing method off. It is not blocking the main thread and as far as I can tell all other functionality continues to work.

Can anyone advise why neither an error or a following message after the `self.conversation =` line would not print?

Answer (score 1):

I figured this out. It was actually a simple mistake on my end. There is a reference to a variable `userSet` which I made from `Set<NSObject>([userId])` but in this instance `userId` was optional so it was wreaking havoc on everything.